# Trying to split a fasta into smaller pieces (total beginner)

Tags: python, biopython, fasta

I'm a biologist with 0 computer skills, but I need a simple script to divide a massive DNA sequence into smaller .fasta for BLAST search. I have been browsing this site for days to find an answer to no avail. I pretty much copied my code from the biopython cookbook. Why is this not working?

```
def batch_iterator(iterator, batch_size):
    entry = True  # Make sure we loop once
    while entry:
        batch = []
        while len(batch) < batch_size:
            try:
                entry = iterator.__next__
            except StopIteration:
                entry = None
            if entry is None:
                # End of file
                break
            batch.append(entry)
        if batch:
            yield batch

from Bio import SeqIO

record_iter = SeqIO.parse(open("/Users/nermin/mainfolder/MTB_NITR203.fasta"),"fasta")
for i, batch in enumerate(batch_iterator(record_iter, 1000)):
    filename = "group_%i.fasta" % (i + 1)
    with open(filename, "w") as handle:
        count = SeqIO.write(batch, handle, "fasta")
    print("Wrote %i records to %s" % (count, filename))
```

Comment: I think you need to fix the formatting.  Please also let us know what happens when you run this, do you get any errors, any results at all?

Comment: I get errors about "method-wrapper" object has no attribute id

Comment: @nermze Edit the full stack trace into your question so we can see it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is caused by actions earlier in the code, specifically:

```
entry = iterator.__next__
```

Which should have been:

```
entry = iterator.__next__()
```

Or in Python 3:

```
entry = next(iterator)
```

My rework of your code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

def batch_iterator(iterator, batch_size):
    entry = True  # Make sure we loop once

    while entry:
        batch = []

        while len(batch) < batch_size:
            try:
                entry = next(iterator)
            except StopIteration:
                entry = False

            if not entry:
                # End of file
                break

            batch.append(entry)

        if batch:
            yield batch

record_iter = SeqIO.parse('/Users/nermin/mainfolder/MTB_NITR203.fasta', 'fasta')

for i, batch in enumerate(batch_iterator(record_iter, 1000), start=1):
    filename = 'group_{}.fasta'.format(i)
    count = SeqIO.write(batch, filename, 'fasta')
    print('Wrote {} records to {}'.format(count, filename))
```

> I need a simple script to divide a massive DNA sequence into smaller
>   .fasta for BLAST search

This is where I have a question about your question.  From your description, I would have expected an input file like:

```
>ZB3243.4 Platypus mRNA for dDFD-w, complete cds.
TTTTAATTTTGCTTTCAATATGACGGCTGTCAATGTTGCCCTGATTCGTGATACCAAGTG
GCTGACTTTAGAAGTCTGTAGAGAATTTCAGAGAGGAACTTGCTCTCGAGCTGATGCAGA
TTGCAAGTTTGCCCATCCACCAAGAGTTTGCCATGTGGAAAATGGTCGTGTGGTGGCCTG
... extremely long sequence 
GCTAGGACAGGGAACAGGGAAGCACTTACAATTATTCCTTGATTTATTCAAAAGAACTGG
GAAAGATGGTTGTAGTTGTCTTTAGCTTCGGTTCAACTGAGTTTCGTTTTGTTAAACAGT
TCAGACCCTCTCACATCATAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

But what your code processes is actually this:

```
>ZB3243.4 Platypus mRNA for dDFD-w, complete cds.
TTTTAATTTTGCTTTCAATATGACGGCTGTCAATGTTGCCCTGATTCGTGATACCAAGTG
GCTGACTTTAGAAGTCTGTAGAGAATTTCAGAGAGGAACTTGCTCTCGAGCTGATGCAGA
TTGCAAGTTTGCCCATCCACCAAGAGTTTGCCATGTGGAAAATGGTCGTGTGGTGGCCTG
>VF42354.1 Rhino Ig active H-chain V-region, subgroup VH-II
TTCATGCAAATATGCTCTCTTTCTTTAGAATATTTCTGTAGGTTTCTTGGGACTGACATT
TAAAACGCCTCACTTTTGAATGTGCACAAAACCTGCTCATTAACATGCATGTGTATAATT
TGTACCTGCAGATCTGATGTTGCATAATACAATCAAATTACTAGATTTTTTAAAGAGAGA
>GS45345.54 Aardvark binding protein.
AACAACACCTGCCACCAGCGTTCCGTTCGCTGCACCAACTACAGGCAATCAGCTGAAATT
CTGAACAGCAGAGTTATGGAGTATCAGAATCTTTCCATGGAAACCTCCATATGGCCTTTC
TATATATATTCTCGTATGTCTTATTCTACCAACACAACAATAAGCGTGTTGCAGTCAATG
... extremely large number of sequences
>GR343245.2 Eggplant subgroup VH-II, mRNA.
TTGCCGCTATGCTCACCCTACTGATGCTTCCATGATTGAAGCGAGTGATAATACTGTGAC
AATCTGCATGGATTACATCAAAGGTCGATGCTCGCGGGAGAAATGCAAGTACTTTCATCC
TCCTGCACACTTGCAAGCCAGACTCAAGGCAGCTCATCATCAGATGAACCATTCAGCTGC
>FG345252.3 Bedbug binding protein 4
TTTTGATTCTCTAAAGGGTCGGTGTACCCGAGAGAACTGCAAGTACCTTCACCCTCCTCC
ACACTTAAAAACGCAGCTGGAGATTAATGGGCGGAACAATCTGATTCAACAGAAGACTGC
CGCAGCCATGTTCGCCCAGCAGATGCAGCTTATGCTCCAAAACGCTCAAATGTCATCACT
>MD2435324.5 Mantis subgroup VH-II, mRNA.
TAAAAATATGCTAATTACAAGTTATAAATCAAACGGAGAGATGGGGGCATGGAGATAGTT
TTTACGTACTGGAGGAAAGTGTGTAAAACCATGGCAATGTCACCTTTTACACAAATGCCA
TTTTCCAAATGCAAATGGCTCATGCTCTTTAGACTACTCTTTGAATAACAAGTAAGATGC
```

Are you processing a massive number of sequences or one massive sequence?

> The input fasta is just 1 massive sequence with around 4 million
>   basepairs (exactly like your first example), but due to its size we
>   cant do blast search. The only thing we need is to divide it into
>   smaller fasta files, preferably less then 1 mb each

We've now established your code isn't designed to do what you want.  So let's attack your problem by running through the data of a single sequence breaking it up into separate FASTA files:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord

FILENAME = '/Users/nermin/mainfolder/MTB_NITR203.fasta'

BPS_PER_FILE = 500000  # base pairs per FASTA file

# There should be one and only one record, the entire genome:
large_record = SeqIO.read(FILENAME, 'fasta')

large_sequence = large_record.seq
large_description = large_record.description

limit = len(large_sequence)

for i, start in enumerate(range(0, limit, BPS_PER_FILE), start=1):
    stop = min(start + BPS_PER_FILE, limit)
    small_sequence = large_sequence[start:stop]
    small_description = large_description + "; base pairs {} to {}".format(start, stop)

    small_record = SeqRecord(small_sequence, id=large_record.id, description=small_description)

    filename = 'group_{}.fasta'.format(i)
    count = SeqIO.write(small_record, filename, "fasta")
    assert (count == 1), "Incorrect record count!"
    print('Wrote {} base pairs to {}'.format(stop - start, filename))
```

Each output file is a single sequence, like the original but smaller, with a modified description that now includes the range of base pairs in each particular file.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the help. The input fasta is just 1 massive sequence with around 4 million basepairs (exactly like your first example), but due to its size we cant do blast search. The only thing we need is to divide it into smaller fasta files, preferably less then 1 mb each. Am i using the wrong setup for this?

Comment: After running your code, i get an output: "Wrote 1 records to group_1.fasta" not sure what to do next.

Comment: @nermze, that's correct, `SeqIO.parse()` deals in *multiple sequences* per file, you only had one sequence so it wrote it out as `group_1.fasta` and was finished.  What we want instead is `SeqIO.read()` to deal with *one sequence* in a file and break its *sequence data* into separate FASTA files.  See my augmented answer with addtional code.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly, now just one last question, after i get the message that: "Wrote 50000 basepairs to group 1.fasta... etc", what do i do then? The files are not my computer, do i need to do anything more? Like do i need to write some more code to save them?

Comment: @nermze, you've lost me there -- when I run the code the files end up on my computer in the working directory (i.e. `pwd`).  Could you have left off the `SeqIO.write()` line?  Doesn't seem likely.  Since we didn't change the directory from within the code and we didn't add a path onto the output file names, the files should be in whatever is your working directory.  Do you have write access to your working directory?  I'm using Python 3.6.0 and BioPython version 1.69

Comment: Seems the problem was related to pycharm ide, i switched to spyder, and the files popped right out. Thanks again, this will save us a ton of time.